# Javascript probleme with 'this' in 'load' method callback

Tags: javascript

I've create a 'Page  Class' and an associated 'load' method.

The loading works perfectly, but i can't modify a property
of that page within the callback method, 
although I cant reference the page name property !!!

```
function Page(page) {
    this.page = page;
    this.firstLoad = true;
    this.pageName = this.page.split('.')[0].split('/')[1];
    this.loaded = false;
}



Page.prototype.load = function () {
    var that = this;
    $("#content").html();
    $("#content").load(this.page, function () {
        $.getScript("PagesViewModel/" + that.pageName + "ViewModel.js");
        that.loaded = true;
    });
}
```

this.loaded is always false !!!

Thank you for your help

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Since your `$.load` method is asynchronous, when your `Page.prototype.load` method returns, `this.loaded` will always be false, and won't switch to true until the `$.load` method returns.

So, in this line here:

```
that.loaded = true;
```

The value of `loaded` will be false right before you set it, and true right after. The problem is that the `Page.prototype.load` method already returned, before your ajax request was even done. Can you post the code of where you are checking the value of `loaded`?

Comment: Thank you Eli.
But i am doing the modification when the load succeed,
at that point the $.load has returned, no ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to define the instance globally in case executing an external ajax call.

```
function test(instancename){
this.instancename = instancename;
this.sayHello = function(data){
alert("hello "+data);
}
$.getJSON(url, params, this.instancename+".sayHello");
}

var k = new test("k");
```

Since the response comes from another source, you need to define your instance globally.

Comment: Thank you, as Eli said i must make a synchronous call.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-req/2592780#2592780)

Comment: No, I don't believe you must make a synchronous call. We need to see where you are checking the loaded value to make sure you aren't checking it before the ajax call has completed.